# Iterate on an array : know when you are on the last element?

Tags: ruby

I need to iterate on an array and need to know when I'm on the last element of the array.

For now I've done like this :

```
my_object.my_array.each_with_index do |obj, i|
  i == my_object.my_array.size - 1 ? do_this : do_that
end
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 3):

```
my_object.my_array[0...-1].each { |obj| do_this(obj) }
do_that(my_object.my_array.last)
```